# Running a command in Cron Tab

Tags: ubuntu, cron, tabs, ddos

I am running ubuntu on a digital ocean droplet. I have been having issues with ddos attacks every now and then that bring down my mysql database. I want to setup a Crontab that starts my mysql server every hour just incase it has gone down. I used

> crontab -e

to open the cron tab file and added

> 0 * * * *  sudo service mysql start

Will this work for what I need? Is there anything wrong with doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume you've read the manual page for `crontab(5)` (the `crontab` file format). Your time specification looks correct. `sudo` is going to give you a problem since you won't be there to enter the password. You could put this in as a `crontab` command under `root` if you have `root` access. You should also do `restart` not `start` in case it's already running.

Comment: Hi, I removed the sudo and I am setting this up under root. I did start because when I run restart it actually brings my database down for a few seconds while it restarts. If I just run start it doesn't do this.

Comment: Yes, `restart` will bring it down if it's already running. If it's already running and you do `start` it might start a second copy, which you probably don't want. You'll need to check if that's the case. Perhaps the server doesn't allow multiple copies to be running, in which case you'll be fine with `start`.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. How would I check to see if I am running more than one?

Comment: You could use something like, `if ! service mysql status | grep "Active: active" > /dev/null ; then service mysql start ; fi`. Check the output of `service mysql status` for a good phrase for active versus not active.

Comment: Ohhh, so would the full thing look like: 0 * * * * if ! service mysql status | grep "Active: active" > /dev/null ; then service mysql start ; fi. Could I put it all on one line like that or do I need to point the cron to a file?

Comment: I would put it in a script file for clarity. You'll want to use the full path of the script file when you reference it or make sure it's in the PATH of the cron job.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks so much!